# Dates will not plot in order on x-axis

Tags: r, excel, date, csv

I am trying to import some .csv files into R for a company. I am trying to basically compare SPC over a selected date domain. When I enter the data into R I have set all other columns to NULL and then I try to plot .csv file. When I do this, my dates are out of order, I have used `sapply(mydata2, class)` 
and find that Date is a factor and SPC is an integer. I am sure this is part of the problem and has been consistently the issue. I have slightly remedied the situation by changing the Excel file (which is a CSV file) date column to a Julian date but for sake of presentation I would much rather have it in short date format. Also it would be great to know how to do this in R as opposed to having to switch to Excel. This has also been my issue for kmeans clustering as well.

Any ideas?

I should also mention that I am basically trying to create a simple function that removes all the nonsense from the Excel file and basically computes the necessary components in various ways. I have roughly 60 more Excel files, split by month to perform this analysis on.

```
mydata2 = read.csv("Copy of Monthly Raw SPC Aug 2015.csv")
mydata2
mydata2$Trailer <- NULL
mydata2$ProducerID <- NULL
mydata2$SampleID <- NULL
mydata2$Producer.Number <- NULL
mydata2$BTUNo <- NULL
mydata2$Route <- NULL
mydata2
plot(mydata2)
sapply(mydata2, class)
```

It is just a simple code for plots, I have tried other things like ordering or boxplots. A sample of the actual data I want to plot is,

```
...
96  42233  27000
97  42233  29000
98  42233   2000
99  42233  38000
100 42234  11000
101 42234 157000
...
```

Instead of the general number, first column would be in a short date formate like 96 would be 8/16/2015. So what happens is when I then go to plot, my box and whisker plot has multiple entries on the same day but the days are all over the graph, I need the same result but the days ordered.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including your code and some of your data.

Comment: your date is a factor, which will not be ordered sensibly. You want to use the function `as.Date` on it, but without sample data, that's all we can tell.

Comment: I should also add that yeah, you are right, when I run sapply when I have dates they show up as factors, but when I switch them to a julian date I think it shows up as an integer or something. Then I can plot it. I want to be able to order dates in plots as well as in plotting kmeans.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out, after some tweeking here it is,

```
 library(chron)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(maptools)
 mydataE = read.csv("Copy of Monthly Raw SPC Aug 2015.csv")
 mydataE
 mydataRAW <- mydataE[-(161:163),]
 attach(mydataRAW)
 Date4 <- as.vector(Date)
 Date4
 Date6 <- dates(Date4, format = c(dates ="m/d/Y"), out.format = c(dates= "d/m/Y")) 
 Date6
 u <- ggplot(dfbest, aes(factor(Date6),SPC))
 u + geom_boxplot()
```

So there it is, it was able to control how I entered the dates and thus order the x-axis, before, my dates would read as, 8/10/2015...8/20/2015...8/31/2015...8/4/2015...8/5/2015... then it would display them on my x-axis as such, so now I have total control on how the x-axis is arranged and the graphs look better. 
Also I removed some of the bad syntax, or at least it looked that way, it seemed that when I would NULL the multiple columns that I did not need, and just plot Date with SPC it would give the boxplot that I wanted, but now with attach() it works provided I use chron and ggplot2.